# Probability for string shorter than 1 in a circle

Tags: probability

> Assume we have circle with radius 1, and we choose randomly A,B points on the circle, Find probability that the distance between A to B is less than 1.

First I plotted the problem:

[image]

I don't really know how A,B where chosen but we can assume that $O$ lies in $(0,0)$ so $x_A,y_A,x_B,y_B\le 1$. Suppose $OA=1,OB=1$  and we asign $\theta=\measuredangle AOB$ we can actiavte cosine law saying $$d_{AB}^2=1+1-2\cdot1\cdot1\cos(\theta)$$. Now $$\begin{align}P(d_{AB}<1)=P(\sqrt{1+1-2\cdot1\cdot1\cos(\theta)}<1)=P(1+1-2\cdot1\cdot1\cos(\theta)<1)=P(cos\theta>\frac 1 2)=P(\theta>\frac \pi 3)=1-P(\theta\le \frac \pi 3)\end{align}$$ but since A,B distribute uniformly we can also assume that theta distribute uniformly on $[0,\pi]$  so the final answer is $\boxed{P(d<1)=\frac 2 3}$ but it seems incorrect somehow because I assumed almost nothing. Am I totally wrong

Comment: Shouldn't you take $[0,2\pi]$ instead? I did not go through the calculation. But it seems  to me that the problem is equivalent to finding the probability of choosing two points $x,y$ on $[0,2\pi]$ such that $|e^{ix}-e^{iy}|\leq 1$.

Comment: I get the same with signs reversed:
$$P(\cos \theta > \frac{1}{2})$$
See my answer for details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG $O = (0,0), A = (1,0), B = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ due to rotation invariance. Then 
$$P(d(A,B) < 1) = P(\Vert (\cos \theta - 1, \sin \theta) \Vert < 1) = P(\cos^2 \theta - 2 \cos \theta + 1 + \sin^2 \theta < 1) = P(1 < 2\cos \theta) = P(\cos \theta > \frac{1}{2})$$
So we have
$$P = \frac{\arccos(\frac{1}{2})}{\pi} = \frac{1}{3}$$
That's what I would get, assuming uniformly distributed on the circle means $A,B = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ with $\theta \sim \text{Uniform}([-\pi, \pi])$

---

**EDIT**
To elaborate on
$$P(\cos \theta > a) = \frac{\arccos(a)}{\pi}$$
We see by symmetry and using the inverse cosine (and by $\cos 0=1$)
$$\cos \theta > a \Rightarrow |\theta| < \arccos(a)$$
For $\theta \in [-\pi, \pi]$ uniformly we have $|\theta| \in [0,\pi]$ uniformly as well and this
$$\cos \theta > a, \theta \in [-\pi, \pi] \Rightarrow |\theta| \in [0, \arccos(a)]$$
and therefor
$$P(\cos\theta > a) = P(|\theta| < \arccos(a)) = \frac{\arccos(a)}{\pi}$$

Comment: I agree I had typo but if $P(cos\theta >0.5)$ it follows $P=\frac 2 3$, isn't it?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis nope. Take a look at the plot to see why
$$P(\cos \theta > a) = \frac{\arccos(a)}{\pi}$$
... it will be $\frac{1}{3}$ for $a = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @CoarguAliquis I elaborated on the formula in an edit to the answer. Is it okay?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine $A$ being chosen first.  Then the string is length less than $1$ if $B$ is within $60^\circ$ one either side of $A$, which is $\frac 13$ of the circle.